# How can I get detachstate on pthread_attr_t?

Tags: c, pthreads

I am looking into the behavior on pthread_attr_t and so I came across some weirdness when I tried to get the detachstate. Following the example here, but the output is not as expected.

https://users.cs.cf.ac.uk/Dave.Marshall/C/node30.html

To do this, I tried to use pthread_attr_getdetachstate.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <pthread.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    int detachstate1=37; //Magic number to recognize output
    int detachstate2=38; //Magic number to recognize output
    pthread_attr_t attr1;
    pthread_attr_t attr2;

    printf("init: %d\n", pthread_attr_init(&attr1));
    printf("PTHREAD_CREATE_DETACHED: %d\n", PTHREAD_CREATE_DETACHED);
    printf("getdetachstate: %d\n", pthread_attr_getdetachstate(&attr1, &detachstate1));
    printf("detach 1 before: %d\n", detachstate1);

    pthread_attr_setdetachstate(&attr1, PTHREAD_CREATE_DETACHED);
    pthread_attr_getdetachstate(&attr1, &detachstate1);
    printf("detach 1 after: %d\n", detachstate1);

    pthread_attr_init(&attr2);
    pthread_attr_getdetachstate(&attr2, &detachstate2);
    printf("detach 2: %d\n", detachstate2);
}
```

And the output looks like,

```
host:~/c_examples$ gcc threads.c -o threads
host:~/c_examples$ ./threads
init: 0
PTHREAD_CREATE_DETACHED: 1
getdetachstate: 0
detach 1 before: 37 // Expected 0 for joinable
detach 1 after: 37 // Expected 1 for detached
detach 2: 38 // Expected 0 or 1, depending on if there is a global dependency between attr1 and attr2.
host:~/c_examples$
```

The reason I wanted to test this was to test if it were possible to have more than one pthread_attr_t (or if the pthread_attr_t had some global dependency), but I ended up with a weird dereferencing problem instead. Any ideas?

BR
Patrik

**EDIT**

After adding the -lpthread flag to gcc, everything worked out (as proposed in https://stackoverflow.com/a/56938217/2903371). Just for the record I want to show the new printout, which shows there are no global dependencies between different pthread_attr_t,

```
host:~/c_examples$ gcc threads.c -o threads -lpthread
host:~/c_examples$ ./threads
init: 0
PTHREAD_CREATE_DETACHED: 1
getdetachstate: 0
detach 1 before: 0
detach 1 after: 1
detach 2: 0
```

Comment: What is the problem? Which line is not expected? Do all the calls to `pthread_attr_getdetachstate` and `pthread_attr_setdetachstate` and `pthread_attr_init` return 0?

Comment: Good point, I will also edit the question. The output "detach 1 before: 37" is expected to be "detach 1 before: 0" (joinable). Then "detach 1 after:" expect to give 1 and "detach 2: " to give whatever the value is here (detach2 is what I wanted to test from the begining).

Comment: On many platforms using `-pthread` is preferred over `-lpthread`. More on this here: stackoverflow.com/q/23250863/694576

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using glibc, not linking with `-lpthread`, and thereby getting the dummy, no-op version of `pthread_attr_getdetachstate` in `libc.so`. This is part of a big family of long-unfixed issues in glibc with a lot of pthread functions. The dummy copies are there so that programs which "don't use threads" can be linked without a dependency on `libpthread.so`, but it results in really serious breakage and least-surprise violations like what you're seeing.

Add `-lpthread` to the end of your linking command line and you should get the correct output.

Comment: Right on spot! Your suggestion worked great. Thanks! Also, now it is clear that that each pthread_attr_t initiated with pthread_attr_init, will get the default attribute values, without internal dependencies. Just for the record.